# Evaluate the integral $ \ \ \int_C z \cos (z) \ dz \ $

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the integral $ \ \ \int_C z \cos (z) \ dz \ $ along the line segment joining $ \ z=2 \ \ \ and \ \ \ z=\frac{\pi}{2}+i \ $

**Answer:**

It is becoming lengthy after using $ z=2t+(1-t) (\frac{\pi}{2}+i), \ \ t \in [0,1] \ $

**Is there any simplest method?**

Answer (score 2):

Since the function is analytic over $\mathbb{C}$, you can apply the FTOC here

$$ \begin{align} 
\int_2^{\pi/2+i} z\cos z \ dz &= [z\sin z + \cos z]\bigg|_0^{\pi/2+i} \\ 
&= \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + i\right)\cosh 1 - i \sinh 1 - 2\sin 2 - \cos 2 \\
&= \left[\frac{\pi}{4}\left(e + \frac{1}{e} \right) - 2\sin 2 -\cos 2 \right] + \frac{i}{e}
\end{align} $$